# Is a pushout $W$ of schemes along a closed subscheme also a pullback?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory

Assume
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
X&\xrightarrow{f}& Y\\
\downarrow && \downarrow\\
Z&\to& W
\end{eqnarray}
$$
is a pushout in the category of schemes (and in particular $W$ is a scheme).

> Is this diagram also a pullback, i.e. $X\cong Z\times_W Y$, if $f$ is a closed immersion? How about an open immersion $f$?

Comment: This feels false to me. If you take $W$ to be a $\mathbb P^1$ glued to itself in two distinct points $Y$ and $Z$ are both $\mathbb P^1$, and the pushout is a scheme. Take $X$ to be a point, and include the point in two different ways into $\mathbb P^1$. The pushout is a nodal curve. Now the fiber product for two $\mathbb P^1$'s mapping to the nodal curve shouldnt be a point, should it?

Comment: The pushout is not a nodal curve, it is just an "axis". It doesn't matter if the two points are equal or not. In this case we have a pullback.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg. Got it. I was being a bit careless about gluing, thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A \to B$ is a surjective homomorphism of commutative rings and $C \to B$ is an arbitrary homomorphism, then for the fiber product $P=A \times_B C$ we have that $\mathrm{Spec}(P)$ is a pushout of $\mathrm{Spec}(A)$ and $\mathrm{Spec}(C)$ over $\mathrm{Spec}(B)$ in the category of schemes (see Karl Schwede's paper "Gluing Schemes and a Scheme Without Closed Points"). Let $I = \ker(A \to B)$. Obviously $P \to C$ is surjective with kernel $\{(a,0) : a \in I\}$. It's image in $A$ is $I$. Hence, $A \otimes_P C = A/I = B$.

This shows that the claim is true in the affine case. More generally, it then also holds when $X \to Y$ *and* $X \to Z$ are closed immersions, because then pushouts exist and look locally as in the affine case above (see Karl Schwede's paper).